# String operation in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have an input string which data is coming in the following format:

- "http://testing/site/name/lists/tasks"
- "http://testing/site/name1/lists/tasks"
- "http://testing/site/name2/lists/tasks"  etc.,

How can I extract only name, name1, name2, etc. from this string?

Here is what I have tried:

```
SiteName = (Url.Substring("http://testing/site/".Length)).Substring(Url.Length-12)
```

It is throwing an exception stating `StartIndex` cannot be greater than the number of characters in the string. What is wrong with my expression? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Am I correctly formated to your question? Your string is `"http://testing/site/name/lists/tasks", "http://testing/site/name1/lists/tasks","http://testing/site/name2/lists/tasks"` or these are 3 different strings?

Comment: In general, if you are hard coding anything to `12` you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: If the format is fix then, try something like Url.SubString(20, (Url.IndexOf("/")-1)) would give your desired result. Refer http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better option will be to use Regex matching/replace

But the following will also work based on the assumption that all the urls will be similar in pattern

```
var value = Url.Replace(@"http://testing/site/", "").Replace(@"/lists/tasks", "");
```

The other option will be to use Uri

```
var uriAddress = new Uri(@"http://testing/site/name/lists/tasks");
```

then breaking down uri parts according to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for regexp:

```
string strRegex = @"http://testing/site/(.+)/lists/tasks";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"http://testing/site/name/lists/tasks" + "\r\n" + @"http://testing/site/name1/lists/tasks" + "\r\n" + @"http://testing/site/name2/lists/tasks" + "\r\n" + @"http://testing/site/name3/lists/tasks";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here. Reference to first group
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `Uri` class to get the desired part:

```
string[] urlString = urlText.Split();
Uri uri = default(Uri);
List<string> names = urlString
    .Where(u => Uri.TryCreate(u, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    .Select(u => uri.Segments.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .ToList();
```

Assuming that the part always start with "name".

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Substring` function with a single argument takes the index of the **starting** charachter and consume all to the end of the string. It will be a little naive, but you can start at charachter **19**: `Url.Substring(19);`